# iOS: Add a background image for the app installation process

Tags: ios, image, ipad, installation, sprite-kit

I want to add a simple background image when my app is being installed. The two images explain everything.
I havent been able to find the solution so far by googling. I did not find any tutorials.

[image: App without background image]

[image: App with background image]

Comment: The only thing you can do here is make sure you've set an app icon for your app, as you cannot change what is shown during installation other than your app icon. Also, just a note: you can take screenshots of your device's screen at any time by pressing the home button and the power button simultaneously.

Comment: No problem! Also I should note (for you and for anyone else finding this via Google) that the screenshots are simply saved into your photos app. Just in case anyone is wondering. Also, I know this doesn't really apply to this question, but you can take screenshots of the iOS Simulator easily by pressing command+S, and those are saved to your desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Add icon to your application bundle and this image will be used. Using `xCode` 5 just open `Images.xcassets` file and add your app icons there as well as splash screens.

Comment: I did that already. The Icons appear in the "Images.xcassets" - "AppIcon". I have 2/3 sets ( IPad Spotlight iOS 7 40pt & iPad App iOS 7 76pt ). The naming is also correct based on the apple HIG. After the installation all icons appear correctly, but still they don´t appear upon installation.

Comment: where you installing the app from?

Comment: From a a web server (it has SSL). I am doing OTA distribution for testing.